# Unable to upload image (without gray strip) more than 640x480px to Google Drive - ESP-CAM via HTTP POST base64 payload

Tags: c, arduino, google-drive-api, base64, esp32

I am solving such a problem for the ESP-CAM platform ...

I have ESP-CAM, which is a microcontroller with an OV2640 camera.

I am sending the photo via HTTPS POST request to Google App Script that save it to my Google Drive.

Payload photo is base64 format. The photo is uploaded and fully visible.

It only works at a low resolution of 640x480 ... Whenever I use a higher photo resolution (800x600 or up to 1600x1200 - 2Mpix) there is a gray bar on each photo ... I suspect that the problem is the base64 payload .... I don't see any problem in software implementation, or memory, because of ESP-CAM has 4MB of external PSRAM memory.

Are there another ways how to upload a photo... What content type to use for payload? image / jpeg payload, application / x-www-form-urlencoded? Are there any other options? I'm also attaching an image of what the image that uploads to me in 800x600 or higher resolution looks like with that gray strip.

**Photo in Google Drive with gray strip:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/utSzQ.png

I would add that if I send the whole image in one color (for example, dark, the whole is black), it will be uploaded correctly without that gray strip ... Could it be that the payload is so long that it is not uploaded? I'm really annoyed about it already.. I don't know on which side is problem.... At encoding, at Google backend of that App Script??

**Code that I am using under Arduino IDE: (ESP Arduino Core 1.0.4)**

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"
#include "Base64.h"
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include "esp_camera.h"
unsigned long cas = 0;
const char* ssid     = "WiFi_SSID";   //your network SSID
const char* password = "WiFi_PASS";   //your network password
const char* myDomain = "script.google.com";
String myScript = "/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec";
String myFilename = "filename=ESP32-CAM.jpg";
String mimeType = "&mimetype=image/jpeg";
String myImage = "&data=";

int waitingTime = 30000; //Wait 30 seconds to google response.

#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

WiFiClientSecure client;
const char* test_root_ca PROGMEM = \
                                   "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
                                   "MIIETDCCAzSgAwIBAgILBAAAAAABL07hSVIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwVzELMAkG\n" \
                                   "A1UEBhMCQkUxGTAXBgNVBAoTEEdsb2JhbFNpZ24gbnYtc2ExEDAOBgNVBAsTB1Jv\n" \
                                   "b3QgQ0ExGzAZBgNVBAMTEkdsb2JhbFNpZ24gUm9vdCBDQTAeFw0wNjEyMTUwODAw\n" \
                                   "MDBaFw0yODAxMjgxMjAwMDBaMEwxIDAeBgNVBAsTF0dsb2JhbFNpZ24gUm9vdCBD\n" \
                                   "QSAtIFIyMRMwEQYDVQQKEwpHbG9iYWxTaWduMRMwEQYDVQQDEwpHbG9iYWxTaWdu\n" \
                                   "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAps8kDr4ubyiZRULEqz4h\n" \
                                   "VJsL03+EcPoSs8u/h1/Gf4bTsjBc1v2t8Xvc5fhglgmSEPXQU977e35ziKxSiHtK\n" \
                                   "pspJpl6op4xaEbx6guu+jOmzrJYlB5dKmSoHL7Qed7+KD7UCfBuWuMW5Oiy81hK5\n" \
                                   "61l94tAGhl9eSWq1OV6INOy8eAwImIRsqM1LtKB9DHlN8LgtyyHK1WxbfeGgKYSh\n" \
                                   "+dOUScskYpEgvN0L1dnM+eonCitzkcadG6zIy+jgoPQvkItN+7A2G/YZeoXgbfJh\n" \
                                   "E4hcn+CTClGXilrOr6vV96oJqmC93Nlf33KpYBNeAAHJSvo/pOoHAyECjoLKA8Kb\n" \
                                   "jwIDAQABo4IBIjCCAR4wDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8w\n" \
                                   "HQYDVR0OBBYEFJviB1dnHB7AagbeWbSaLd/cGYYuMEcGA1UdIARAMD4wPAYEVR0g\n" \
                                   "ADA0MDIGCCsGAQUFBwIBFiZodHRwczovL3d3dy5nbG9iYWxzaWduLmNvbS9yZXBv\n" \
                                   "c2l0b3J5LzAzBgNVHR8ELDAqMCigJqAkhiJodHRwOi8vY3JsLmdsb2JhbHNpZ24u\n" \
                                   "bmV0L3Jvb3QuY3JsMD0GCCsGAQUFBwEBBDEwLzAtBggrBgEFBQcwAYYhaHR0cDov\n" \
                                   "L29jc3AuZ2xvYmFsc2lnbi5jb20vcm9vdHIxMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFGB7ZhpFDZfK\n" \
                                   "iVAvfQTNNKj//P1LMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCZIivuijLTDAd+3RsgK1Bq\n" \
                                   "lpEG2r5u13KWrVM/fvWPQufQ62SlZfLz4z0/WzEMfHmEOpeMDx+uwbzy67ig70H9\n" \
                                   "vDGp/MlC5kS+HlbKdYuySTGZ/urpcWSGeo/l1WERQ+hAuzEM4tsYi5l0OGGrJICM\n" \
                                   "+ag710nWZooYc8y8BjmLEDIODdOx9+9mExBZSMjPAcqZzJBymNs67cunu+JscI6m\n" \
                                   "nmhj7Y+3LQWJztlU9k6rHkbbMEk/9mrgAfC8zYTUOfdVjgMVcdOdNO2dxtHIqsWE\n" \
                                   "OTsN/SknUh6Dq0gjhVhQs5XGC7Mm4xYtqDDcA1BtXNEMzSqhR5rPIBvbQ4gfwvzg\n" \
                                   "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
void setup()
{
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  client.setCACert(test_root_ca);
  ArduinoOTA.setPort(3232);
  ArduinoOTA
  .onStart([]() {
    String type;
    if (ArduinoOTA.getCommand() == U_FLASH)
      type = "sketch";
    else // U_SPIFFS
      type = "filesystem";

    // NOTE: if updating SPIFFS this would be the place to unmount SPIFFS using SPIFFS.end()
    Serial.println("Start updating " + type);
  })
  .onEnd([]() {
    Serial.println("\nEnd");
  })
  .onProgress([](unsigned int progress, unsigned int total) {
    Serial.printf("Progress: %u%%\r", (progress / (total / 100)));
  })
  .onError([](ota_error_t error) {
    Serial.printf("Error[%u]: ", error);
    if (error == OTA_AUTH_ERROR) Serial.println("Auth Failed");
    else if (error == OTA_BEGIN_ERROR) Serial.println("Begin Failed");
    else if (error == OTA_CONNECT_ERROR) Serial.println("Connect Failed");
    else if (error == OTA_RECEIVE_ERROR) Serial.println("Receive Failed");
    else if (error == OTA_END_ERROR) Serial.println("End Failed");
  });

  ArduinoOTA.begin();
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("STAIP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("");

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;  // UXGA|SXGA|XGA|SVGA|VGA|CIF|QVGA|HQVGA|QQVGA
  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  config.fb_count = 1;

  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  }
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  ArduinoOTA.handle();
  if ((millis() - cas) >= 60000 || cas == 0) {
    cas = millis();
    saveCapturedImage();
  }
}

void saveCapturedImage() {
  Serial.println("Connect to " + String(myDomain));
  client.stop();

  if (client.connect(myDomain, 443)) {
    Serial.println("Connection successful");

    camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb) {
      Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
      delay(1000);
      ESP.restart();
      return;
    }

    char *input = (char *)fb->buf;
    char output[base64_enc_len(3)];
    String imageFile = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < fb->len; i++) {
      base64_encode(output, (input++), 3);
      if (i % 3 == 0) imageFile += urlencode(String(output));
    }
    String Data = myFilename + mimeType + myImage;

    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);

    Serial.println("Send a captured image to Google Drive.");

    client.println("POST " + myScript + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + String(myDomain));
    client.println("Content-Length: " + String(Data.length() + imageFile.length()));
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println();

    client.print(Data);
    int Index;
    for (Index = 0; Index < imageFile.length(); Index = Index + 1000) {
      client.print(imageFile.substring(Index, Index + 1000));
    }

    Serial.println("Waiting for response.");
    long int StartTime = millis();
    while (!client.available()) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(100);
      if ((StartTime + waitingTime) < millis()) {
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("No response.");
        //If you have no response, maybe need a greater value of waitingTime
        break;
      }
    }
    Serial.println();
    while (client.available()) {
      Serial.print(char(client.read()));
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connected to " + String(myDomain) + " failed.");
  }
  client.stop();
}

//https://github.com/zenmanenergy/ESP8266-Arduino-Examples/
String urlencode(String str)
{
  String encodedString = "";
  char c;
  char code0;
  char code1;
  char code2;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c == ' ') {
      encodedString += '+';
    } else if (isalnum(c)) {
      encodedString += c;
    } else {
      code1 = (c & 0xf) + '0';
      if ((c & 0xf) > 9) {
        code1 = (c & 0xf) - 10 + 'A';
      }
      c = (c >> 4) & 0xf;
      code0 = c + '0';
      if (c > 9) {
        code0 = c - 10 + 'A';
      }
      code2 = '\0';
      encodedString += '%';
      encodedString += code0;
      encodedString += code1;
      //encodedString+=code2;
    }
    yield();
  }
  return encodedString;
}
```

**Google App Script for saving photo to my Google Drive --> ESP-CAM directory:**

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data);
  var nombreArchivo = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM HH:mm")+".jpg";
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameters.mimetype, nombreArchivo );


  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("ESP32-CAM");
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder("ESP32-CAM");
  }
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Completed.")
}
```

Thanks for help! - Martin

Comment: I think that in your case, the data is sent as the query parameter. In this case, I thought that the whole data might not be sent because the data size is smaller than the maximum length of URL. [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/417142) I think that this might be the reason of your issue. So how about sending the data as by including the request body? By this, the whole data can be sent to Web Apps. In this case, please be careful the event object retrieving the post data. [Ref2](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#eventobject)

Comment: Looks like the data is sent in the body and not as a query parameter.

Comment: Hello there... Maybe i know, where is problem... It looks like ESP is saving that photo to RAM, not to PSRAM and it is not enough for whole photo. 
But i am beginner and I don't know how to use ps_malloc (it is malloc function as in standard C that works for PSRAM). 

I want to use fb->buf with fb->len in malloc and also then for base64 encoding and urlencoding functions that are using fb->buf with fb->len.... 
Also i need to use that String imageFile with malloc too... 

PSRAM have 4MB...